# Add new printer to a new print server through csv files problem

Tags: powershell, csv, printing, export-to-csv

I hope someone could help me there! ;-)

First, what I need to do is create a new print server by importing the printers from 2 existing print servers. On each server, I export the ports via this PowerShell script:

```
Get-PrinterPort -ComputerName 16MOS001045 | export-csv -NoTypeInformation C:\temp\printer-ports.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

This created a csv file for me with all of my current ports. I then replace all the port names in this file with the new ports (before the port name was the printer name and we changed to the ip addresses). Then I try to import this csv file on my new print server via this PowerShell Script, but i receive an error.

```
$PrintServer = "16MOS191005"
$PrinterPortsCsvList = Import-csv C:\temp\printer-ports.csv
$i = 1
foreach ($line in $PrinterPortsCsvList)
    {
    Add-PrinterPort -Name $line.Name -PrinterHostAddress $line.Name -ComputerName $PrintServer -verbose
    if ($i -le 5) {$i++; &pause}
    }
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pzs4.png)

My question here is,do I have this error because I changed the information in the csv file? Because if I import the file without modifying it, the ports are added to my new print server. What is the procedure to import this csv file with my modifications?

Or is there an easier way to do it? Also, I have another csv file that I modified with all my renamed printers with the new nomenclature, but I also have an error.

I hope it's a bit clear ...

[CSV files Contents before with names and then with ip's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Rfx.png)

Comment: I have tried this and cannot duplicate your error.  What changes did you make in the CSV file?  That is the best place to start.  Did you "Quote" your new name?

Comment: @ShamusBerube, I had 2 screenshots on my original message, the one with Jr01I0001 is the original export and the one with Ip is the one I'm trying to import. I modified the original by deleting the name by replacing it with the ip

Comment: What happens if you make the PrinterHostAdress an IP address instead of a printer name?

Answer (score 0):

$line.name is a powershell object. -Name only takes strings.  If you wrap the object with $() it will output a string.

$($line.Name) is not correct for "-PrinterHostAddress" it should be an IP address.

```
Add-PrinterPort -Name $($line.Name) -PrinterHostAddress $($line.Name)  -ComputerName $PrintServer -verbose
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you for your answer. I tried it and still have the same error.